# How to se ConEmu to split console and keep same dir?

Tags: powershell, conemu

I [followed these steps](http://conemu.github.io/en/ShellWorkDir.html#PowerShell) to make ConEmu `StoreCWD` on PowerShell...

But what now? How can I setup to open new tabs/split screen in the same dir as the previous window (on PowerShell)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First I followed the steps on ["Shell Working Directory"](http://conemu.github.io/en/ShellWorkDir.html#PowerShell)

After that I found that the `Shell` command can take a `new_console:s50V` parameter. So I unassigned the shortcuts for screen split and assigned them on custom macros

[image: macros]

```
# ctrl + shift + o
Shell("new_console:s50V", "{Shells::PowerShell (Admin)}", "", "%CD%")

# ctrl + shift + e
Shell("new_console:s50H", "{Shells::PowerShell (Admin)}", "", "%CD%")
```